# How to save logic branching in lines, not in columns

Tags: google-forms

Is there any way to save new information that comes from logic branching questions into new lines, instead of new columns?
I'm trying to have something like this on my Answer Spreadsheet:

```
Provider  -  Material  -  Amount  -  Cost
Paul      -  Paper     -  2 bags  -  $10
Paul      -  Penclis   -  1 box   -  $15
Paul      -  Books     -  2 books -  $20
```

But that I only have to ask once who the provider is, and then ask for material, amount and cost through logic branching.

Comment: Add a sample form / spreadsheet to be considered and a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible.

One alternative is to create a report to display the responses the way that you want. You could use spreadsheet formulas to create the report.

---

[Google editors Help](http://support.google.com/docs)